# Como descargo un Pdf que ya he generado usando HttpGet desde blazor server

Tags: .net-6.0

Estoy intentando que el usuario pueda descargae el pdf para que lo almacene en su dispositivo y luego si quiera pueda descargarlo.

```
Codigo de blazor:
   Con este codigo blazor intento descargar el pdf.

 public async Task DescargarPDf()
 {
     try
     {
         var fileName = "wwwroot/factura.pdf";
         var filenamedescarga = "factura_descargada.pdf";
         var filepath = Path.Combine("wwwroot", "Descarga", filenamedescarga);
         var fileContent = await http.GetByteArrayAsync($"https://localhost:7185/File/DownloadFile/{fileName}");

         //Guarda el archivo localmente


         System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filepath,fileContent);

         await js.InvokeVoidAsync("window.open", $"Descarga/{filenamedescarga}","_blank");

         System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName();


     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         Message = ex.Message; 
     }
     


    
 }
```

Cuando intengo Descargar el PDf me Arroja la excepcion 404 not Found

SOy nuevo en esto asi que disculpen si no hice bien la pregunta.

Comment: Dado que el nombre de tu PDF es fijo porque simplemente no colocar el enlace en un `<a href="{enlace}">Descargar PDF</a>`  ?

Answer (score 0):

Parece que lo estas guardando localmente antes de abrir una nueva ventana para visualizarlo.

Podrias intentar hacerlo de esta forma

```
public async Task DescargarPDF()
{
    try
    {
        var fileName = "factura.pdf";
        var fileContent = await http.GetByteArrayAsync($"https://localhost:7185/File/DownloadFile/{fileName}");

        // hace referencia al tipo de contenido y las cabeceras para la descarga del archivo
        var contentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
        {
            FileName = fileName
        };

        
        httpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", contentDisposition.ToString());
        httpContext.Response.Headers.Add("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff");

        // Escribe el contenido del archivo en la respuesta que armamos arriba
        await httpContext.Response.Body.WriteAsync(fileContent);

        
        await js.InvokeVoidAsync("window.open", "", "_blank");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Message = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

Lo que haces con este cambio es primero con el http.GetByteArrayAsync descargas el contenido del archivo
Esto deberia de poder abrir el pdf y que al usuario le permita descargar o no el PDF

Espero te ayude, saludos!

Comment: Gracias me ayudo mucho